# BadAuthentication error while uploading video on youtube from ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I am working on an app in which my replace the Oauth2 to client login.
What I did already is Successfully implemented Ouath2 API now I get access token. What I think I have to assign access token to GDataServiceGoogleYouTube Object. And other things will remain same but NO sucess now it gives me

Error
***Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataServiceDomain error 403.)" UserInfo=0x15dd9760 {Error=BadAuthentication, error=BadAuthentication}***

GDATA API use GDataServiceGoogleYouTube method which needs user ID but in Oauth2 I can't find answers what is have is access token now please guide me